# slow scrolling when using responsive bootstrap theme

Tags: scroll, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a bootstrap 3 template and have noticed on some that scrolling is not smooth and kind of bumpy. I am not even sure what to look for. This only happens in Chrome. It does NOT happen in Safari or Firefox.

Is this a javascript or css problem? I have never run across this before.

This seems to happen worse in Chrome for mac, but also happens in chrome for windows.

It seems to happen when I make the window smaller and then make it bigger again. If I leave the window the same size, it seems to scroll fine.

Link:

http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com --> Click Sales then resize the window in Chrome and then scroll down and then up. You will notice it is very bumpy and not smooth

Comment: a link so we can see it?

Answer (score 1):

`:root { scroll-behavior: auto; }`

Add this simple code to your custom CSS file.

"scroll-behavior" declared as "smooth" in bootstrap css/bootstrap.reboot.css.
So we need to overwrite it using our custom css.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the **jquery.nicescroll plugin** that is used with the theme, the function     `jQuery.fn.scrollTop` make the problem, it takes more than 75% from the cpu when run. my solution is :

1. You are using the ***jquery.nicescroll plugin version 3.4.0*** use the latest version currently [version 3.5.0 available](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-nicescroll/downloads/list).
2. If not working as expected, downgrade to version 3.2.0 I'm using it with my site without any problem.
3. Also check that if the **`hwacceleration`** in the Configuration parameters of the plugin is set to **(default: true)**.

***Update 1:***

**nicescroll plugin** is a solution to have a custom scrollbars compatible with desktop, tablet and phone devices and to override the default scrollbars of the browser " [more information her](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) ", *"you didn't see the diffrence because the plugin used in your project works when your browser window under 767px"* so another solution if you don't need it you can remove the plugin from your files by following this steps:

- Delete the plugin file **(jquery.nicescroll.js)** from your script folder.
- Delete the plugin link from all your files.
- Delete the plugin function lines **(21 to 36), (49 to 66), (149)** from **(unicorn.js)** file.

***Update 2:***

I made some tweaks for the **(unicorn.js)**, [download it from her](http://rapidshare.com/share/073318ED26ED931F59848AEB731A9E82), then replace your original one.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried 3.2.0 and it has the same problems. What does Nice Scroll even do? I tried it on multiple operating systems and I don't notice a difference in the toolbar.

Comment: If you go to the demo site now, I have removed nice scroll and it still happens. The way I reproduce it is by resizing the window very small then scroll, then resize the window back, then try scrolling again.

Comment: follow the update 2 and let me know if the problem still, thanks

Comment: The problem went away, but it looks like certain classes such as "fixed"are not being added/removed which means the menu in mobile doesn't stay on top. I guess this isn't a huge deal, but do you think $(window).scroll(function(){ is the problem?

Comment: The problem was in scrollTop function, when inspect it, I found a lot of cpu usage near 50% on it.